# Getting jacoco code coverage at the same as running tests

Tags: gradle, spock, jacoco

I have jacoco set up for my project. 
I can do:
`gradle cleanTest test`
followed by
`gradle jacocoTestReport`
and get code coverage

This means two steps. Is there any way, I can just pass a switch to `gradle test` and get it

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

> If the Java plugin is also applied to your project, a new task named
>   `jacocoTestReport` is created that depends on the `test` task.

So just call `gradle jacocoTestReport`, the `test` will also be invoked first.

edit : if you really want to call the `test` task, just add this in your build.gradle :

```
test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
```